# Rails: Form input doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails so I've been practicing with a basic CRUD application. Everything seems to work except for when I submit a new form entry it doesn't save any of the data. I've now set up some validations so it won't even submit now. Yet I can still edit other entries to add new data. So my edit is working.

Here's my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params[:post])
        if @post.save
            redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your email was sent!"
        else 
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])

        if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
            redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your email has been updated."
        else
            render "edit"
        end 
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your email has been deleted"
    end

private
    def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :message)
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <h2>Errors:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <br>
  <br>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <br>
  <br>

  <%= f.label :message %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :message %>
  <br> 

  <%= f.submit "Send Email" %>
<% end %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit</h1>

<%= render "form" %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Emails</h1>
<hr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <p><em>Name:</em> <%= link_to post.name, post %></p>
    <p><em>Email:</em> <%= post.email %></p>
    <p><em>Message:</em> <%= post.message %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %>
    | <%= link_to "Delete", post, :method => :delete %>
    </p>
    <hr>
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "Add a New Post", new_post_path %></p>
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Email</h1>
<p>Send an email:</p>

<%= render "form" %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p><em>Name:</em> <%= @post.name %></p>
<p><em>Email:</em> <%= @post.email %></p>
<p><em>Message:</em> <%= @post.message %></p>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small mistake in your `create` action

change from

```
@post = Post.new(post_params[:post])
```

to

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```